# Insert data as point in time, retrieve data as time range

Tags: php, mysql

#### Environment

PHP: 5.6
MySQL: 5.5 (MariaDB)

#### Data

From an adminitration website I get the following data as an array construct:

```php
[
    0 => [
        0 => ['factor' => 1.25], // hour from 0:00 to 0:59
        1 => ['factor' => 1.25], // hour from 1:00 to 1:59
        2 => ['factor' => 1.25], // hour from 2:00 to 2:59
        .
        .
        .
        23 => ['factor' => 1.25]
    ], // monday
    1 => [
        0 => ['factor' => 1.0], // hour from 0:00 to 0:59
        1 => ['factor' => 1.0], // hour from 1:00 to 1:59
        2 => ['factor' => 1.0], // hour from 2:00 to 2:59
        .
        .
        .
        23 => ['factor' => 1.0]
    ], // tuesday
    .
    .
    .
    6 => [
        0 => ['factor' => 1.0], // hour from 0:00 to 0:59
        1 => ['factor' => 1.0], // hour from 1:00 to 1:59
        2 => ['factor' => 1.0], // hour from 2:00 to 2:59
        .
        .
        .
        23 => ['factor' => 1.0]
    ] // sunday
]
```

The data represents the days and hours where i.e. a customer has to pay extra charges ("factor") for services.

Inserting this data into a table isn't a problem, it could look like the following table (where "#" is just a number for the row and "some_fk" is the connection to the customer, but is not relevant here):

```
| #  | day | hour | factor | some_fk |  
|----|-----|------|--------|---------|  
| 1  | 0   | 0    | 1.25   |         |  
|----|-----|------|--------|---------|  
| 2  | 0   | 1    | 1.25   |         |  
|----|-----|------|--------|---------|  
| 3  | 0   | 2    | 1.25   |         |  
|----|-----|------|--------|---------|  
| 4  | 0   | 3    | 1.25   |         |  
|----|-----|------|--------|---------|  
| 5  | 0   | 4    | 1.25   |         |  
|----|-----|------|--------|---------|  
| 6  | 0   | 5    | 1.25   |         |  
|----|-----|------|--------|---------|  
| 7  | 0   | 6    | 1.0    |         |  
|----|-----|------|--------|---------|  
| 8  | 0   | 7    | 1.0    |         |  
|----|-----|------|--------|---------|  
| 9  | 0   | 8    | 1.0    |         |  
|----|-----|------|--------|---------|  
| 10 | 0   | 9    | 1.0    |         |  
.  
.  
.  
|----|-----|------|--------|---------|  
| 23 | 0   | 22   | 1.0    |         |  
|----|-----|------|--------|---------|  
| 24 | 0   | 23   | 1.0    |         |  
|----|-----|------|--------|---------|  
| 25 | 1   | 0    | 1.0    |         |  
|----|-----|------|--------|---------|  
| 26 | 1   | 1    | 1.5    |         |  
|----|-----|------|--------|---------|  
| 27 | 1   | 2    | 1.5    |         |  
.  
.  
.  
|----|-----|------|--------|---------|  
| 37 | 1   | 12   | 1.5    |         |  
|----|-----|------|--------|---------|  
| 38 | 1   | 13   | 1.5    |         |  
|----|-----|------|--------|---------|  
| 39 | 1   | 14   | 1.25   |         |  
|----|-----|------|--------|---------|  
| 40 | 1   | 15   | 1.25   |         |  
|----|-----|------|--------|---------|  
| 41 | 1   | 16   | 1.25   |         |  
|----|-----|------|--------|---------|  
| 42 | 1   | 2    | 1.25   |         |  
.  
.  
.
```

#### The challenge / the problem

The inserting and the retrieval in this "administrative" form (arrays in and arrays out) won't happen often, so that is not the primary issue, but it purport the data structure.

Most of the time I need the data (only retrieve, no write) in a time range, where the "factor" column indicates the beginning and the end of the range. I.e (from the table above):

- range1: factor == 1.25; lines 1 - 6; day=0,hour=0 - day=0,hour=5
- range2: factor == 1.0; lines 7 - 25; day=0,hour=6 - day=1, hour=0
- range3: factor == 1.5; lines 26 - 38; day=1,hour=1 - day=1,hour=13
- range4: factor == 1.25; lines 39 - ...; day=1,hour=14 - day=...,hour=...

Maybe it is too challenging to get the data as range (and at the moment I cannot imaginge a data format, that can be used in PHP later), so every first row where the factor is different to the one in the previous row, could do the trick:

- factor == 1.25; line 1
- factor == 1.0; line 7
- factor == 1.5; line 26
- factor == 1.25; line 39

#### Question(s)

1. Is there a way to get the data as "range" (or rows where the factor changes) out of the table and data structure (given above) as a SQL query?

   - If not, could I change the table/data structure to get the data using SQL?
2. If there is no "SQL way" at all, what would be the recommended way:

   - insert the data as given above and process the ranges on every request programmatically?
     -or-
   - think about a different data structure, process the ranges before saving them and retrieve the ranges via SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking and testing a few possible solutions, I'll post the way I finally solved it, if someone steps into similar questions:

Because the SQL solution is not that simple (or even possible), I thought about my second question combined with saving only the changes of the factor with day and hour in the database.

The parameter for the `reduceServiceTimes()` function is the array from the question. It returnes an array with the following structure:

```php
[
    ['day' => 0, 'hour' => 0,'factor' => 1.25],
    ['day' => 0, 'hour' => 6,'factor' => 1.0],
    ['day' => 1, 'hour' => 1,'factor' => 1.5],
    ['day' => 1, 'hour' => 14,'factor' => 1.25],
    .
    .
    .
]
```

The function `fillServiceTimes()` takes an array with the same structure as parameter and returnes an array like in the question.

When getting the data from the administrative website, I use the following function in PHP to reduce the complete dataset to only the changing points on "time":

```php
function reduceServiceTimes($serviceTimes) {

    // prepare current factor
    $currentFactor = null;

    // prepare reduced service times
    $reducedServiceTimes = [];

    // walk through days
    for($day = 0; $day <= 6; $day++) {

        // walk through hours
        for($hour = 0; $hour <= 23; $hour++) {

            // check if first entry
            if($day == 0 && $hour == 0) {

                // add first entry
                $reducedServiceTimes[] = [
                    'day' => 0,
                    'hour' => 0,
                    'factor' => $serviceTimes[0]['hours'][0]['factor']
                ];

                // remember current factor
                $currentFactor = $serviceTimes[0]['hours'][0]['factor'];
            } else {

                // check last factor
                if($serviceTimes[$day]['hours'][$hour]['factor'] != $currentFactor) {

                    // first entry
                    $reducedServiceTimes[] = [
                        'day' => $day,
                        'hour' => $hour,
                        'factor' => $serviceTimes[$day]['hours'][$hour]['factor']
                    ];

                    // remember current factor
                    $currentFactor = $serviceTimes[$day]['hours'][$hour]['factor'];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // return
    return $reducedServiceTimes;
}
```

The returned array could easily inserted into the database structure mentioned in my question.

To get the completly filled array back for the website, I use the following function to fill the gaps between the changing points of "time" with the same factor:

```php
function fillServiceTimes($rows) {

    // prepare complete list
    $completeServiceTimes = [
        0 => [],
        1 => [],
        2 => [],
        3 => [],
        4 => [],
        5 => [],
        6 => [],
    ];

    // walk through rows
    for($i = 0; $i < count($rows); $i++) {

        // simplify days and hours
        $day = $rows[$i]['day'];
        $nextDay = ($i == count($rows) - 1 ? 6 : $rows[$i + 1]['day']);
        $hour = $rows[$i]['hour'];
        $nextHour = ($i == count($rows) - 1 ? 24 : $rows[$i + 1]['hour']);
        $value = ['factor' => floatval($rows[$i]['factor'])];

        // check if start and end are the same day
        if(($day == $nextDay) || ($nextDay == $day + 1 && $nextHour == 0)) {

            // check if next hour is 0
            if($nextHour == 0) {
                $nextHour = 24;
            }
            $completeServiceTimes[$day] += array_fill($hour, $nextHour - $hour, $value);
        } else {

            // walk from day to next day
            for($currDay = $day; $currDay <= $nextDay; $currDay++) {

                // check if first day and no complete day
                if($currDay == $day && $hour > 0) {
                    $completeServiceTimes[$currDay] += array_fill($hour, 24 - $hour, $value);
                // check if last day and no complete day
                } elseif($currDay == $nextDay && $nextHour <= 23) {
                    $completeServiceTimes[$currDay] += array_fill(0, $nextHour, $value);
                // any other complete day
                } else {
                    $completeServiceTimes[$currDay] += array_fill(0, 24, $value);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // return
    return $completeServiceTimes;
}
```

Hopefully this may help someone else...